# Validate if call was made after telprompt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

I want to validate if user tapped on **Call** button or **Cancel** button after telprompt

Current code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", [personDetails valueForKey:@"phone"]]];
    [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(called:) name:@"UIApplicationSuspendedNotification" object:nil];

-(void)called:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped Call button");
}
```

if Call button was tapped then application will be terminated and go into background so just add an observer for the `UIApplicationSuspendedNotification` notification.

Comment: No it will now. I tested it and it is working very fine.

Comment: I did not say that it would not work, I'm just saying that it not 100% solution. Because if the dialog is presented and the app get pushed to the background by the user, either hitting the home button or some other app goes to the foreground you also get this notification. Also using the `telprompt:` scheme is not recommended, since it is not an official scheme.

Answer (score 2):

First `telprompt:` is not a documented URL schema and should not be used. Since Apple can change the way it used at any moment.

Second since data is passed back to your app, you will not be able to detect a if call was made. You might be able to detect if you use the [`CoreTelephony`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html). But getting this to work require your app to run in the background and you might have to misuse some background mode for this which will make Apple reject your app.

Can you explain why you want to detect if there was a call made?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I used `tel://` instead of using `telprompt://` and make my own `UIAlertView`. This way you could detect if the call option is tapped from the `UIAlertView`'s delegate.

Comment: can you share your code? because i don't think that you can add your own alert for tel:// as it is system provided alert instead.